# Weird results from Elastic search when using a synonym analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

When i run this query

```
"multi_match": {
    "query": "paper copier ", 
    "fields": [ "allStringFields" ],
    "type": "cross_fields",
    "operator": "and",
    "analyzer": "synonym"   
}
```

i get 1342  results

But when i run this query  (notice word order)

```
 "multi_match": {
    "query": " copier paper ", 
    "fields": [ "allStringFields" ],
    "type": "cross_fields",
    "operator": "and",
    "analyzer": "synonym"   
 }
```

I get zero results

I am using synonym analyzer  and it is the cause for this  behavior

Is there a solution to this ?

Comment: My index definition looks similar to what you wrote here   , still does not work .

Answer (score 1):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result. In the below example, I have taken two synonyms `table` and `tables`

```
I get zero results
```

Please go through your index mapping once again. According to the below example, the search keyword is `table chair`, this is to be searched in both the fields `title` and `content`. The below query will return the documents that contain both `table AND chair`. To get a detailed explanation, refer to ES documentation on the [Multi match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) and [synonym token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html).

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "table, tables"
            ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonym_filter"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{ "title": "table chair" }
{ "title": "tables chair" }
{ "title": "table fan" }
{ "title": "light fan", "content": "chair" }
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "table chair",
            "operator": "and",
            "type":"cross_fields",
            "fields": [
                "title","content"
            ],
            "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "synonym",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.7227666,
        "_source": {
          "title": "table chair"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "synonym",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.3862942,
        "_source": {
          "title": "tables chair"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Searching `table chair` or `chair table`, gives the same search result as shown above.